# How can I relate the osm2po osm_source_id to data in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2po

I created and imported OpenStreetMap (OSM) data into Postgres using osm2po:

e.g. `java -Xmx8g -jar osm2po-4.6.9/osm2po-core-4.6.9-signed.jar config=osm2po.config.eu_xc prefix=eu tileSize=x,c europe-latest.osm.bz2`

and `psql -d osm2po_eu_xc -q -f "eu_2po_4pgr.sql"`

which creates the table *eu_2po_4pgr* and has datasets with columns *"osm_source_id*", *"osm_target_id"*.

I created and imported the exact same osm data (using the exact same bz2 file) using osm2pgsql (0.69)

e.g. `time osm2pgsql -smuc europe-latest.osm.bz2   -d osm_eu`

which creates table like *planet_osm_point* which has a *"column osm_id"*.

I can't find the *"osm_source_id"* in say *planet_osm_point*.

What I would like is to join the osm2po table with the original OSM Data, in order to have the complete information.

Is that possible or am I missing something fundamentally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The osm_* attributes should match. If not, there is sth. wrong. How many rows does your planet_osm_point have? There should be around 600 Mio. If it's dramatically smaller I assume there's sth. wrong with your osm import.

Comment: They should match? Ok, thank you. I'm using the europe osm and select count(*) n from planet_osm_point;
   n    
--------
 24141269
so I need to look into the osm2pgsql import.

Comment: and this already gives a smaller numer than the osm table so that's a marker that I got the osm2pgsql import wrong: select count(*) n from (select distinct osm_source_id from eu_2po_4pgr) t;
    n     
----------
 25728084

Comment: the entire planet contains about 2 Gig Nodes. I remember one of my last tests on Europe where I got a number of around 600 Mio nodes. So there must be sth. wrong with your osm2pgsql import. But I'm sorry. I cannot help you at this point.

Comment: Have you tried to search in planet_osm_line? Routes are lines not points.