# Finding vertices that osm_source_id refers to

Tags: osm2po

I've been reading through [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69400/how-can-i-relate-the-osm2po-osm-source-id-to-data-in-openstreetmap) from many years ago, and I have a similar issue.

Namely, I'm assuming that the `osm_source_id` and `osm_destination_id` columns in hh_2po_4pgr refer to vertex ids of OSM nodes. Is this assumption correct?

If so, I've noticed that I only find a couple osm vertex ids that match with the ones given for the `osm_source_id` and `osm_destination_id` of a particular edge (row of the hh_2po_4pgr table). This behavior seems counterintuitive given that osm2po references osm vertex ids specifically and works from the same OSM XML that I give osm2pgsql to isolate vertex ids.

Any thoughts?